# How to use result set from one query in second query on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query a table once to obtain ID numbers based on a given condition, then I need to use those ID numbers to retrieve another set of values, all on the same table. Here's the first query:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM ih_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_edd_discount_uses'
AND meta_value > '0'
```

This works fine to retrieve the `post_id` numbers. Now I need to run the equivalent of this query:

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM ih_postmeta
WHERE post_id = '1088' 
    AND meta_key = '_edd_discount_code'
```

This works, except I need to able to loop through the values obtained from the first query and not have `WHERE post_id =` hard coded.

Here's a sample from the table in question for a specific `post_id`:

```
|meta_id|post_id|    meta_key      |meta_value
|1822   |1088   |_edd_discount_uses|8
|1823   |1088   |_edd_discount_code|ls100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IN with a subquery to get what you want:

```
SELECT meta_value
FROM ih_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id
                  FROM ih_postmeta
                  WHERE meta_key = '_edd_discount_uses'
                  AND meta_value > '0') 
    AND meta_key = '_edd_discount_code'
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I kept thinking in terms of FOR EACH, need to get used to SQL logic and syntax. Thanks!